# Any way to set an image to anything but 100% of its native size in Outlook using CSS?

Tags: html, css, email, responsive-design, outlook

I'm attempting to develop an email with some limited fluid resizing capability. As we all know, this is a bit of a crap shoot, but im giving it a try anyway because ive seen it done. I'm stuck on one hangup- i have a 2 column email with image features and text in each column. On mobile devices the 2 columns stack on top of eachother. I would like to be able to insert any image and have it adapt to fit its parent, OR at very least have outlook recognize when i give it a class that sets the image at a defined width. Right now when i render in outlook, the image is displayed 100% of its native width and height, no matter what css tricks i try to apply. Would love some insight!

```
<style>
    body {
    max-width:600px;
    margin:auto;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
img {
    height:auto;
    max-height:auto;
    width:100%;
    display:block
}
table {
    max-width:600px!important;
    border-spacing:0!important;
    border:none;
}
td {
    cellpadding:0px;
    border-spacing:0px;
}
tr {
    cellpadding:0px;
    border-spacing:0px;
}
.headline {
    padding:0px;
    font-size:30px;
}
.paragraph {
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:100%
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {
    .containerbox {
        width:520px!important;
        max-width:520px!important;
        margin:0 auto!important;
        clear:both!important;
    }
    table {
        width:100%;
        display:block
    }
    .headline {
        font-size:20px;
    }
    .paragraph {
        font-size:14px;
        line-height:100%
    }
}
</style>
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
<style type="text/css">
    .outlook {height:auto; width:290px; max-width:290px; display:block}
</style>
<![endif]-->


<body>
<div style="background-color:#ffffff;">
<center>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="     max-width:600px!important; width:100%;"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><table align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" ><![endif]-->
   <tr>
        <td>
<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<table align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="48%" ><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><table align="left" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="290" ><![endif]-->
<tr>
<td class="outlook"><img class="outlook" src="shot.jpg" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headline">
Some headline
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="paragraph">
Some copy is here Some copy is here Some copy is here Some copy is here Some copy is here 
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--[if !mso]><!-->
<table align="right" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="48%"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte mso 9]><table  align="right" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="290" ><![endif]--><tr>
<td class="outlook"><img class="outlook" src="shot.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="headline">
Some headline
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="paragraph">
Some copy is here Some copy is here Some copy is here Some copy is here Some copy is here 
</td>
</tr>

</table>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
</center></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find the answer in the [Word 2007 HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook 2007 (Part 1 of 2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa338201(office.12).aspx) article in MSDN.

The issue appears to be the use of named styles and the CLASS attribute. Try to code the styles in-line at each tag, that seems to work well.